# Generator of $\tilde{H}_n(S^n;G)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm struggling with the following exercise:

Let $\sigma_n: \Delta^n \to\Delta^n/ \partial \Delta^n$ be the quotient map. Show that $[\sigma_n]$ generates $\tilde{H}_n(S^n;G)$ with $G$ any abelian group.

My idea was to use induction on $n$:

Consider the pair $(B^n,\partial B^n)$ and its long exact sequence:

$$\cdots \tilde{H}_n(B^n;G)\stackrel{\pi_*}\to \tilde{H}_n(B^n,\partial B^n;G) \stackrel{\partial_*} \to \tilde{H}_{n-1}(\partial B^n;G) \stackrel{i_*}\to \tilde{H}_n(B^n;G) \to \cdots$$

Since $B^n$ is contractible we get an isomorphism:

$$\tilde{H}_n(B^n, \partial B^n;G) \cong \tilde{H}_{n-1}(\partial B^n;G) \cong \tilde{H}_{n-1}(S^{n-1};G)$$

We also have the fact that $(B^n, \partial B^n)$ is a good pair so we also get:

$$\tilde{H}_n(B^n, \partial B^n;G) \cong \tilde{H}_n(B^n / \partial B^n;G) \cong \tilde{H}_n(S^n;G)$$

As a next step I tried to show that the singular $n$-simplex $\sigma_n$, which equals the quotient map as described above, gets mapped to $\sigma_{n-1}$ the quotient map. However I've not been able to do the explicit computation of it. This seems rather complicated and I'm pretty sure there is an easier way and if not I hope someone can help me out here.